# SVN tag log, what does this mean?

Tags: svn, tomcat, tags

I create a tag 7.0.42, why there is three entries?

```
/home/user/svn/stuff/Tomcat $ svn log https://example.com/stuff/Tomcat/tags/7.0.42/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r9 | user | 2013-10-11 14:17:59 -0400 (Fri, 11 Oct 2013) | 2 lines

tag the initial version downloaded.

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r8 | user | 2013-10-11 11:35:10 -0400 (Fri, 11 Oct 2013) | 3 lines

Import Tomcat source.


------------------------------------------------------------------------
r7 | user | 2013-10-11 11:16:00 -0400 (Fri, 11 Oct 2013) | 1 line

create Tomcat project
------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/user/svn/stuff/Tomcat $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the log command is following the copy that created the tag.  If you don't want it to do that use:

`svn log --stop-on-copy https://example.com/stuff/Tomcat/tags/7.0.42/`

Comment: Logs follow copy history by default. Use --stop-on-copy to disable this behavior, which can be useful for determining branch points......what does this mean? I copy only once to create the tag, am I?

Comment: What it means is that when you copy something Subversion remembers where you copied it from.  When you ask for a log of a location it follows the history of the path you asked for, if at some point it finds that location was copied from another location it then continues following the source of the copy.  This is why for instance when you create a tag you can see the history of the branch that tag was made off of.